# sending email back/forth internally django

Tags: django, django-models, django-email

Currently I have a custom email notification implemented and it works when you post a comment you receive an email which notify you about the posted comment, now the thing is that this is happening internally in the system, so basically the staff (`account_handler's`) are talking to each other and get notify via email.

Now the problem that I'm facing is that `account_handlers` that leave a comment on my thread for example, all of us will receive an email and be notify that comment was made in that thread, but when I respond I'm not sending anything, so no returning email's when you reply to the comment in the thread, the emails are only going in one direction, so the question is how can I fix this?

In my model I'm using this code for comment email notification setup:

```
class LeadContact(models.Model):
    # models here
    account_handler = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='handling_leads',
                                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # some custom function here

    def send_comment_posted_emails(self, comment):
        comment_user = comment.user
        comment_text = comment.comment
        handler_user = self.account_handler
        handler_email = handler_user.email

        if handler_email is not None and handler_email != comment_user.email:
            current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
            leads_url = self.get_view_url() + "#CommentsDiv"
            ctx = {"leads_url": leads_url, "site_name": current_site.name, "leads_sn": self.serial_number,
                   "poster_name": user_util.get_user_full_name_or_user_name(comment_user),
                   "comment_text": comment_text}
            subject = render_to_string("vinclucms_sales/email/email_sales_comment_posted_subject.txt", ctx)
            subject = "".join(subject.splitlines())
            message = render_to_string("vinclucms_sales/email/email_sales_comment_posted_message.html", ctx)

            MailManager.send_mail_with_error_handler(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [handler_email],
                                                     message_html=message)

    class Meta:
        # Meta code here
```

Signal which is sending email:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=EmailAddress)
def handle_email_address_save(sender, instance, created, update_fields, **kwargs):
    confirm = account_settings.ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL
    must_confirm = instance.must_confirm if hasattr(instance, 'must_confirm') else False
    warning("handle_email_address_save called for email "
            + str(instance.email) + ", created = " + str(created)
            + ", confirm = " + str(confirm) + ", must_confirm = " + str(must_confirm))
    if confirm and not instance.verified and must_confirm:
        instance.send_confirmation()
        warning("handle_email_address_save sent confirmation")


# TODO: move to signals.py in quotes module
@receiver(comment_was_posted)
def handle_comment_posted(sender, comment, request, **kwargs):
    if comment.content_type.model == 'leadcontact':
       leadcontac = LeadContact.objects.get(pk=comment.object_pk)
       leadcontac.send_comment_posted_emails(comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an obvious solution to this problem, in [EmailMessage-Object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) there is a

> reply_to: A list or tuple of recipient addresses used in the
> “Reply-To” header when sending the email.

My django verison is `1.8.9` so by using this and adding it to my `MailManager` I've solve the problem.

Note to self: Read the documentation!!!